# Will restoring or upgrading Windows solve problems after a Service Pack installation?

Tags: windows-vista, updates, service-pack

I downloaded updates Service Pact 1,2 & 3.

Now when I put a DVD in the computer, my camera software comes up, and I can no longer send pictures by E-mail.

- Do I have to uninstall software and re-install to fix a software
  problem? (Camera software)
- Could I use "restore" to a previous date to solve other problems?
- And finally if I install Windows 7 would that solve the burning disk
  problem plus a few other things?

**OS**: Vista Home Pemium 
**Model**: HP Pavilion dv9000

Comment: This may be the worst question title I've ever seen on these sites.  Something like "I can't send photos by email" would have been far better.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, there is only Service Pack 1 and 2 for windows Vista, not 3.

you can uninstall service packs:

**[How to uninstall Windows Vista service packs as a troubleshooting step](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948537)**

but this is rather a last resort,  first i would re-install the program that is not working properly (e.g. the camera software), check the manufacturer's website and see if an updated version (or patch) is available.

if you let us know the name and version of the software, this might be a helpful bit of information too.

Comment: You are correct, there is no SP3 for Vista

Comment: And you're right on the second part too ;-) Jim should reinstall programs he thinks aren't working or install another app that does the job. Uninstalling service packs is a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are eager to install windows 7. So its better to install windows 7 and in this media center is the one where you can do your media or camera works can done in a simple manner.